# Curl / Grep save output to file with URL only if match

Tags: bash, scripting, curl

I want to save output `.txt` file only if it matches Grep with Curled URL.

example what I have right now:

```
xargs -d '\n' -I LINE bash -c "curl -s -o - 'LINE/matchme!'| grep -o 'matchme!'" > saveme.txt < domain.txt
```

which reads URLs from `domain.txt` file, however it does create `saveme.txt` even when string is not matched + without curled URL inside `saveme.txt` if it does match.

Expected output in `saveme.txt`

https://example.com/matchme!?random=param - matchme!

https://example2.com/matchme! - matchme!

https://example3.com/matchme! - matchme!

How would I construct such script?

Comment: What's the expected output in `saveme.txt`? The URL plus the complete curl output if there was a match?

Comment: @Freddy Yes! :) - without curl output just curled URL + grep
Edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern='matchme!'
while IFS= read -r domain; do
  url="$domain/matchme!"
  curl -s "$url" | grep -q "$pattern" && printf '%s - %s\n' "$url" "$pattern" >> saveme.txt
done < domain.txt
```

Add `-F` to `grep`'s options if you're looking for a fixed string.

Comment: Thanks! as asked in the question can we make it so the "saveme.txt" file is created ONLY IF pattern is found, when nothing is found we wont create "saveme.txt"

Comment: Edited. Now it appends to `saveme.txt` if there is a match. You have to delete the file yourself before the next run.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)